# repeated calling directory path in URL

Tags: php, html, css

OK.here is my folder strusture.

- Gass

  - alarm-system

    - 16-zone

      - A16GSM

        - overview.php
      - A16

        - overview.php

When i run my project in localhost,click on the A16GSM menu(dropdown menu), the URL  shows exactly the same as my directory path. However when i try to click on other menu that is A16 menu, the URL shows repeated calling of directory path as shown below.

```
http://localhost/GASS-2110/alarm-system/16-zone/A16GSM/alarm-system/16-zone/A16/overview.php
```

what cause this problem and how am i going to fix it?

Here are the codes:

```
 <li><a href="alarm.php" id="alarm" target="_self" style="<?php echo $colors;?>;"><span>Alarm</span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown"> 

                    <li><a href="alarm-system/16-zone/A16GSM/overview.php">
                  <h1>A16 GSM - High Security System</h1></a></li>
                  <li><a href="alarm-system/16-zone/A16/overview.php">
                  <h1>A16 - Advance Alarm System</h1></a></li>
```

p/s: sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links need to have a leading slash added, like this:

`<a href="/alarm-system/16-zone/A16GSM/overview.php">`

Comment: @Christ Herbert. nope its not working. may i know why is this happening?

Comment: Of course it's not working, because `alarm-system` is not in your web root folder - `GASS-2110` is. So when referring to the domain root, you have to include that folder name as well.

Comment: Does that have the leading slash that you were just told about ...? Dude, please go learn some _basics_ on how paths in HTML work.

Comment: @CBroe ya i got it! thanks. <a href="/GASS-2110/alarm-system/16-zone/A16GSM/overview.php">